# Why can I call a function from a typeclass instance directly in the REPL (like compare from Ord)?

Tags: haskell

When I am in a REPL like GHCI with Prelude, and I write

```
*> compare 5 7
LT
```

Why can I call that function (`compare`) like that directly in the REPL?

I know that `compare` is defined in typeclass `Ord`. The typeclass definition for `Ord` of course shows that it is a subclass of `Eq`.

Here is my line of reasoning:
`5` has type `Num a => a`, and `Num` typeclass is not a subclass of `Eq`. 
Also,

```
Prelude> :t (compare 5)
(compare 5) :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Ordering
```

So, there is an additional constraint imposed here when I apply a numeric type argument. when I call `compare 5 7`, the types of the arguments are narrowed to something that does have an instance of `Ord`. I think the narrowing happens to the default concrete type associated with the typeclass: in the case of `Num`, this is `Integer`, which has an instance of `Real`, which has an instance of `Ord`.

However, coming from a non-functional programming background, I would have imagined that I would have to call `compare` on one of the numbers (like calling it on an object in OOP). If `5` is `Integer`, which does implement `Ord`, then why do I call `compare` in the REPL itself? **This is obviously a question related to a paradigm shift for me and I still didn't get it. Hopefully someone can explain.**

Answer (score 10):

The [type defaulting](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-01-04-type-defaulting-in-haskell.html) here comes into play. The interpreter can derive that `5` and `7` need to be of the same type, and members of the `Ord` and `Num` typeclass. The default for a `Num` is `Integer`, and since `Integer` is an instance of `Ord` as well, we can thus use `Integer`.

The interpreter thus considers `5` and `7` to be `Integer`s here in that case, and thus it can evaluate the function and obtain `LT`.

GHCi has some additional defaulting rules, described in the [GHCi documentation](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules).

Answer (score 9):

Methods like `compare` are associated with types, not particular values. The compiler needs to be able to deduce the type in order to select the correct typeclass instance, but that doesn't require any special assistance.

The type of `compare` is

```
compare :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Ordering
```

Thus any of its arguments (of type `a`) can be used to look up the `Ord` instance.

As you correctly assumed, in the `compare 5 7` example, the types of `5` and `7` default to `Integer`. Thus `a` in the `compare` type is deduced to be `Integer` and the `Ord Integer` instance is selected.

This selection does not necessarily go through a function argument. Consider e.g.

```
read :: (Read a) => String -> a
```

Here it is the result type that drives instance selection, but the type checker is just fine with it:

```
> read "(2, 3)" :: (Int, Int)
(2,3)
```

(What would the OO equivalent be? `"(2, 3)".read()`?)

In fact, methods don't even have to be functions:

```
maxBound :: (Bounded a) => a
```

This is a polymorphic value, not a function:

```
> maxBound :: Int
9223372036854775807
```

Class instances are uniquely connected to types, so as long as the type checker has enough information to figure out what that type variable represents, everything works out. That is, in

```
someMethod :: (SomeClass foo) => ...
```

`foo` has to appear somewhere in the type signature `...` so the type checker can resolve `SomeClass foo` from the way `someMethod` is used at any given point (at least in the absence of certain language extensions).